# Error during ng serve: An unhandled exception occurred: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: angular

When running `ng serve` I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
See "/tmp/ng-CatGSs/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I tried `npm i` and co, but no success. Unit tests with `ng test` run fine.

Answer (score 0):

My `angular.json` has:

```
projects.<MYPROJECT>.architect.serve.options.ssl: true
```

However, the key and certificate pointed to by

```
projects.<MYPROJECT>.architect.serve.options.sslKey: "../localhost-ssl-certificates/localhost-key.pem"
projects.<MYPROJECT>.architect.serve.options.sslCert: "../localhost-ssl-certificates/localhost-cert.pem"
```

did not exist.

I created them using mkcert which fixed the problem:

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libnss3-tools mkcert
mkcert -install
mkdir ../localhost-ssl-certificates
mkcert \
  -key-file ../localhost-ssl-certificates/localhost-key.pem \
  -cert-file ../localhost-ssl-certificates/localhost-cert.pem \
  localhost
```